# The exact meaning of the term *Alma Mater*

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate, terminology

More often than not, the term *Alma Mater* is applied to one's place of undergraduate studies.

Would it be reasonable of me to apply this term to a university where I received my doctoral degree?

Comment: Usually the "Alma Mater" charge a fees for their alumni to be part of them. It is therefore statistically more relevant to try to aim for the bachelor degree's holders ... there are more of them!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is literally nothing in the term specifying an undergraduate program. From Wikipedia: Alma mater (Latin: alma mater, lit. 'nourishing mother'; pl: almae matres) is an allegorical Latin phrase used to proclaim a school that a person has attended or, more usually, from which one has graduated.

Sure, you can use it for your doctoral institution. I doubt anyone will notice.